# Calculating sum of 2 fields in a row

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I have been trying to calculate sum of sum of 2 fields in a row in PIG

eg

```
jnd: {count_d::server: chararray,count_d::uniq_visitors: long,count_d2::server: chararray,count_d2::uniq_visitors: long}

 A 12 A 14
 B 13 B 16
```

I want to return

```
 A 26
 B 29
```

How do I do it in PIG using in-built SUM function????? I am not able to make it work

I managed to do it using a UDF, but is it possible to do it without UDF??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator in a `FOREACH`

```
C = FOREACH jnd GENERATE count_d::server, count_d::uniq_visitors + count_d2::uniq_visitors
```